# Problems reloading UITextField when application restarts

Tags: iphone, xcode, multitasking

I'm trying out a simple exercise whereby i save the contents of a UITextField to a file when an app closes down.

My header file is as follows:

```
#define kFileName @"file.plist"

@interface applicationLaunchViewController : UIViewController {

    UITextField *text1;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;

-(void)applicationSaveFile:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(NSString *)dataFilePath;
```

My implementation file:

```
@implementation applicationLaunchViewController

@synthesize text1;

-(void)applicationSaveFile:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [array addObject:text1.text];
    [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [array release];

}

-(NSString *)dataFilePath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDictionary = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDictionary stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFileName];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        self.text1.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        [array release];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationSaveFile:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Is there something within this code that i'm missing? When i launch the app it runs fine, no errors. I close the app, still OK, but when i close the app through multitasking and go to re-open i get the SIGKILL message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should state your questions title more detailed. "what am i doing wrong?" could be any type of question.

Answer (score 0):

If you close your app via Multitasking your application mostly gets a Sigkill which you cannot catch easily (maybe never).

You are saving text of a `UITextField` which is done by a user I assume. You should save your data on `applicationDidEnterBackground`. If your app is in background a user cannot write sth. in your textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to unsubscribe to your notification when the app is terminated (you terminate the app from multitasking window).

I believe the app delegate has a method that gets called right before the app terminates that you could use to write to your file before closing or request additional time to write to the file before finishing or unsubscribe from your notification.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. You've helped alot